# How to fix this “TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found”

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to combine the cell values (strings) in a dataframe column using groupby method, separating the cell values in the grouped cell using commas. I ran into the following error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found
```

The error occurs on the following line of code, see the code block for complete codes:

```
toronto_df['Neighbourhood'] = toronto_df.groupby(['Postcode','Borough'])['Neighbourhood'].agg(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

It seems that in the groupby function, the index corresponding to each row in the un-grouped dataframe is automatically added to the string before it was joined. This causes the TypeError. However, I have no idea how to fix the issue. I browsed a lot of threads but didn't find a solution. I would appreciate any guidance or assistance!

```
# Import Necessary Libraries

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Use BeautifulSoup to scrap information in the table from the Wikipedia page, and set up the dataframe containing all the information in the table

wiki_html = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(wiki_html, 'lxml')
# print(soup.prettify())
table = soup.find('table', class_='wikitable sortable')
table_columns = []
for th_txt in table.tbody.findAll('th'):
    table_columns.append(th_txt.text.rstrip('\n'))

toronto_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=table_columns) 

for row in table.tbody.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    row_data = []
    for td_txt in row.findAll('td'):
        row_data.append(td_txt.text.rstrip('\n'))
    toronto_df = toronto_df.append({table_columns[0]: row_data[0],
                                    table_columns[1]: row_data[1],
                                    table_columns[2]: row_data[2]}, ignore_index=True)
toronto_df.head()

# Remove cells with a borough that is Not assigned
toronto_df.replace('Not assigned',np.nan, inplace=True)
toronto_df = toronto_df[toronto_df['Borough'].notnull()]
toronto_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
toronto_df.head()

# If a cell has a borough but a Not assigned neighborhood, then the neighborhood will be the same as the borough
toronto_df['Neighbourhood'] = toronto_df.groupby(['Postcode','Borough'])['Neighbourhood'].agg(lambda x: ','.join(x))
toronto_df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
toronto_df.head()
```

The expected result of the 'Neighbourhood' column should separate the cell values in the grouped cell using commas, showing something like this (I cannot post images yet, so I just provide the link):

https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/imageAssetProxy.v1/7JXaz3NNEeiMwApe4i-fLg_40e690ae0e927abda2d4bde7d94ed133_Screen-Shot-2018-06-18-at-7.17.57-PM.png?expiry=1557273600000&hmac=936wN3okNJ1UTDA6rOpQqwELESvqgScu08_Spai0aQQ

Comment: if your column `Neighbourhood` has `NaN` values, either drop them or fill them with some string with `fillna()` and then execute this code. Since `NaN` is a float.

Comment: The issue, I think is, the `agg` function, since that's where the string operation is happening. Might be a `NaN` problem (although the link doesn't really show any blank cells in the table)

Comment: Is indeed a `NaN` problem. The row with Postcode = 'M7A' has a blank Neighbourhood (once it gets parsed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `NaN` is a float, so trying to do string operations on it doesn't work (and this is the reason for the error message)

Replace your last part of code with this:
The filling of the nan is done with boolean indexing according to the logic you specified in your comment

```
# If a cell has a borough but a Not assigned neighborhood, then the neighborhood will be the same as the borough
toronto_df.Neighbourhood = np.where(toronto_df.Neighbourhood.isnull(),toronto_df.Borough,toronto_df.Neighbourhood)
toronto_df['Neighbourhood'] = toronto_df.groupby(['Postcode','Borough'])['Neighbourhood'].agg(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```