# How to solve TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to use groupby method to combine the cell values (strings) of a column. But I faced the following error.

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

The line which is giving error is

```
docs_per_topic = docs_df.groupby(['Topic'], as_index = False).agg({'Doc': ' '.join})
```

My original dataset has only one column ['Articles']. Below is the code where I read my CSV file.

```
data = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
data = data['Articles']
```

I cluster the articles and now I want to combine articles that are in the same cluster. For that, I am using the below code.

```
docs_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Doc"])
docs_df['Topic'] = cluster.labels_
docs_df['Doc_ID'] = range(len(docs_df))
docs_per_topic = docs_df.groupby(['Topic'], as_index = False).agg({'Doc': ' '.join})
```

I browsed for answers, I find this: [How to fix this “TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998672/how-to-fix-this-typeerror-sequence-item-0-expected-str-instance-float-found) but I couldn't understand how to implement it in my case. I am fairly new to python. I would appreciate any suggestions or solutions to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems some missing values, so is possible remove rows with them before `groupby`:

```
docs_per_topic = docs_df.dropna(subset=['Doc']).groupby(['Topic'], as_index = False).agg({'Doc': ' '.join})
```

Or in `groupby` in lambda function:

```
docs_per_topic = docs_df.dropna(subset=['Doc']).groupby(['Topic'], as_index = False).agg({'Doc': lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna())})
```

Another problem should be mixed values - strings with floats convert it to strings:

```
docs_per_topic = docs_df.assign(Doc = docs_df['Doc'].astype(str)).groupby(['Topic'], as_index = False).agg({'Doc': ' '.join})

docs_per_topic = docs_df.groupby(['Topic'], as_index = False).agg({'Doc': lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str))})
```